# User Following System in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm learning laravel atm and trying to implement a twitter style follower feed. 
So far I have the following

standard users table (id, username ect)

subscriptions (aka followers) table that contains user_id, subscriber_id, timestamps

My User model contains the following relationship

```html
public function subscriptions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'subscriptions', 'user_id', 'subscriber_id')->withTimestamps();
}
    

    public function subscribers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'subscriptions', 'subscriber_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

I am now trying to load a users list of subscriptions
ie. User 14 follows user 15

```html
$subscriber = Auth::user()->id;
    
        
        $user = User::find($subscriber);
        
        
        $userids = $user->subscriptions->lists('user_id');

        return $userids;
```

I use this code to fetch the current logged in user and find their subscriptions. $userids should return a list of IDs that the current logged in user is subscribed to. However it just produces an empty array despite the records existing in the DB. (it should return 15, but returns only [] )

Am I going wrong somehere or missing out on something?

Answer (score 1):

Get the current user's subscribers using:

```
$subscribers = Auth::user()->subscribers;
```

and you can send subscribers to any view and use

```
@foreach ($subscribers as subscriber)
   {{ $subscriber->name }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `lists` method call you are asking to return a `user_id` column from the results of `subscriptions` method call. However the `subscriptions` call returns a relationship object that gives results from the users table not the pivot table `subscriptions`. The `user_id` column is found only on the pivot table and not on the `users` table. That's why you are getting empty result. Here I am getting an array with `NULL` values.
Try with: `$userids = $user->subscriptions->lists('id');`

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply. The return results are still null. Do my user model relationships look okay, this baffles me as it makes sense in my head!

Comment: Have you tried using `subscribers` instead of `subscriptions`? You may have the relations backwards from what you are expecting.